# Need help in implementing Repository Pattern with Custom Membership ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, custom-membershipprovider

I am implementing Repository Pattern in one of my project based on ASP.NET MVC4 and N-Tier Architecture. I am little confused as how to implement Custom Membership with Repository Pattern. Here are how I have implemented my classes so far.

//***Generic Repository***

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
void Add(T entity);
void Delete(T entity);
void Update(T entity);
IQueryable<T> GetAll();
T FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);
IQueryable<T> FilterBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);
}
```

//***Repository Base Class***

```
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
private STNDataContext _stnDataContext;
private readonly IDbSet<T> _dbSet;

protected Repository(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
{
DatabaseFactory = databaseFactory;
_dbSet = StnDataContext.Set<T>();
}

protected IDatabaseFactory DatabaseFactory { get; private set; }
public STNDataContext StnDataContext
{
get { return _stnDataContext ?? (_stnDataContext = new STNDataContext()); }
}
public void Add(T entity)
{
_dbSet.Add(entity);
_stnDataContext.Commit();
}

public void Delete(T entity)
{
_dbSet.Remove(entity);
}

public void Update(T entity)
{
_dbSet.Attach(entity);
_stnDataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
_stnDataContext.Commit();
}

public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
{
return _dbSet.ToList().AsQueryable();
}

public T FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
return FilterBy(expression).SingleOrDefault();
}

public IQueryable<T> FilterBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
return GetAll().Where(expression).AsQueryable();
}
```

//***User Repository Interface***

```
public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<User>
{
}
```

//***User Repository***

```
public class UserRepository : Repository<User>, IUserRepository
{
public UserRepository(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
: base(databaseFactory)
{
}
}
```

//***Heres my Business Logic Layer***

//***Generic Service Interface***

```
public interface IService<T>
{
void Add(T entity);
void Delete(T entity);
void Update(T entity);
IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
T FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);
IEnumerable<T> FilterBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);
}
```

//***Service Base***

```
public class Service<T> : IService<T> where T : class 
{
public void Add(T entity)
{
throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public void Delete(T entity)
{
throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public void Update(T entity)
{
throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
{
throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public T FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public IEnumerable<T> FilterBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
throw new NotImplementedException();
}
}
```

//***User Service Interface***

```
public interface IUserService : IService<User>
{
}
```

//***User Service Implementation***

```
public class UserService : Service<User>, IUserService
{
private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
private readonly IRoleRepository _roleRepository;

public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository, IRoleRepository roleRepository)
{
_userRepository = userRepository;
_roleRepository = roleRepository;
}

public IList<User> GetAllUsers()
{
return _userRepository.GetAll().ToList();
}

public User GetUser(int id)
{
return _userRepository.FindBy(x => x.UserId == id);
}

public User GetUser(string userName)
{
return _userRepository.FindBy(x => x.Username.Equals(userName));
}

public void CreatUser(User user)
{
_userRepository.Add(user);
}

public IList<User> GetUsersForRole(string roleName)
{
return _userRepository.FilterBy(x => x.Role.RoleName.Equals(roleName)).ToList<User>();
}

public IList<User> GetUsersForRole(int roleId)
{
return _userRepository.FilterBy(x => x.Role.RoleId == roleId).ToList<User>();
}

public IList<User> GetUsersForRole(Role role)
{
return GetUsersForRole(role.RoleId);
}

}
```

I am not very sure on Am I going the right way? If yes how do i implement my UserService class.

If no, what changes do i need to implement.

Any help on this is highly appreciable. Thanks in advance**strong text**

Comment: This is probably something for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `IService<T>` looks an awfully lot like your `IRepository<T>` interface. That looks like a completely useless abstraction to me. Consumers can use the `IRepository<T>` abstraction directly. If your intension is to add features (such as cross-cutting concerns) to the `IService<T>` implementations; use [decorators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) instead.

Besides, why have an empty (non-generic) `IUserRepository`? There is no use over using the `IRepository<User>` directly. If your intention is to add extra methods to this `IUserRepository` later on, please don't. This interface, and the implementations of this interface, will start growing too big, get hard to maintain, and become hard to extend parts of your code base, because you will be violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Instead, give custom -user specific- operations their own classes (one class per operation), hidden by a generic interface, just as you already do with the `IRepository<T>`.

The following two articles describe an attractive way of creating a more maintainable system by defining smaller focused classes that each encapsulate a single query or use case, which can be placed on top of your repository pattern:

- [Meanwhile… on the command side of my architecture](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91)
- [Meanwhile… on the query side of my architecture](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92)

Last note. Your `UserService` class, looks a lot like the `MembershipProvider` class from the .NET framework. Why not use that class? There is a [very interesting library](https://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.mvccontrib) that allows you to [create a membership provider for MVC in a more structured, dependency-friendly way](http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/09/a-more-structured-membershipprovider/). You should definitely take a look.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. The plan is to use Decorators in the BLL layer. The architecture is evolving simultaneously as I go on developing further and then reviewing the same.

Comment: Hi Steven, I am new to ASP.NET MVC and want to implement my own log in and do not want to use built in membership. I am herewith attaching my UserService. CAn you help me by providing source code implementing Log-in using my UserService class. Do not need entire project. Just need Log-in view and controller.

Comment: Unless you want to do something really exotic, you *should* use the `Membership` abstraction that is supplied by ASP.NET. What you need however is to write your own `MembershipProvider` implementation (on top of that absrtaction). By doing this, you hook in to the membership infrastructure of ASP.NET, which gives a lot of benefits. Besides, you're using a model that other developers are familiar with.

Comment: Hi Steven, I made changes to my architecture as per your suggestions. It helped me a lot. The problem I am facing is I am able to get data from database but when I am trying to save entity using unitofwork class it is not firing any query to DB. It might that by datacontext is no more open. If I provide you with source code can you help me identify Am I doing it incorrect? A help on this is highly appreciable. Thanks

Comment: @pbhalchandra: Create a new question here at stackoverflow and post a link to that question when you did. This allows you to get help from more people than only me.